# SQL first of every month

Tags: sql, sql-server

Supposing that I wanted to write table valued function in SQL that returns a table with the first day of every month between the argument dates, what is the simplest way to do this?

For example `fnFirstOfMonths('10/31/10', '2/17/11')` would return a one-column table with `11/1/10, 12/1/10, 1/1/11`, and `2/1/11` as the elements.

My first instinct is just to use a while loop and repeatedly insert first days of months until I get to before the start date. It seems like there should be a more elegant way to do this though.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: You're doing iterative/row-by-row logic in a relational database - there won't be a very elegant way.  You're essentially hammering nails with a screwdriver.  It'll work but don't be surprised if it doesn't work very well.

Comment: I realize that the hammering nails with a screwdriver analogy is kind of appropriate here, but sometimes you kind of have to do the best you can with the tools you've got b/c of design trade-offs that are maybe out of your control.  It's sql server btw.

Comment: @marc I was also pointing out the bug in that comment

Comment: @richard - I just ran it and it looks ok.  The main reason that I accepted it was that it was simpler than yours though.

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi: sorry to disappoint you - my preliminary tests show that your solutions is much slower ... and btw: I usually also know what I'm talking about when it comes to SQL Server. ....

Comment: @marc I would love to see your test code that shows otherwise in any version of SQL Server. Ah, of course CTE is not comparable in 2000 since it doesn't exist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this would work without being inside a function:

```
DECLARE @LowerDate DATE 
SET @LowerDate = GETDATE()

DECLARE @UpperLimit DATE
SET @UpperLimit = '20111231'

;WITH Firsts AS
(
    SELECT
        DATEADD(DAY, -1 * DAY(@LowerDate) + 1, @LowerDate) AS 'FirstOfMonth'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        DATEADD(MONTH, 1, f.FirstOfMonth) AS 'FirstOfMonth'
    FROM
        Firsts f
    WHERE
        DATEADD(MONTH, 1, f.FirstOfMonth)  <= @UpperLimit
)   
SELECT * 
FROM Firsts
```

It uses a thing called CTE (Common Table Expression) - available in SQL Server 2005 and up and other database systems.

In this case, I start the recursive CTE by determining the first of the month for the `@LowerDate` date specified, and then I iterate adding one month to the previous first of month, until the upper limit is reached.

Or if you want to package it up in a stored function, you can do so, too:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetFirstOfMonth(@LowerLimit DATE, @UpperLimit DATE)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS 
   RETURN
      WITH Firsts AS
      (
          SELECT
             DATEADD(DAY, -1 * DAY(@LowerLimit) + 1, @LowerLimit) AS 'FirstOfMonth'
          UNION ALL
          SELECT
             DATEADD(MONTH, 1, f.FirstOfMonth) AS 'FirstOfMonth'
          FROM
             Firsts f
          WHERE
             DATEADD(MONTH, 1, f.FirstOfMonth)  <= @UpperLimit
       )    
       SELECT * FROM Firsts
```

and then call it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.GetFirstOfMonth('20100522', '20100831')
```

to get an output like this:

```
FirstOfMonth
2010-05-01
2010-06-01
2010-07-01
2010-08-01
```

PS: by using the `DATE` datatype - which is present in SQL Server 2008 and newer - I fixed the two "bugs" that Richard commented about. If you're on SQL Server 2005, you'll have to use `DATETIME` instead - and deal with the fact you're getting a time portion, too.

Answer (score 2):

```
create function dbo.fnFirstOfMonths(@d1 datetime, @d2 datetime)
returns table as return
select dateadd(m,datediff(m,0,@d1)+v.number,0) as FirstDay
from master..spt_values v
where v.type='P' and v.number between 0 and datediff(m, @d1, @d2)
  and dateadd(m,datediff(m,0,@d1)+v.number,0) between @d1 and @d2
GO
```

#### Notes

- **master..spt_values** is a source for general purpose sequence numbers in SQL Server
- **dateadd(m, datediff(m** is a technique for working out the first day of month for any date
- **+v.number** is used to increase it by one month each time
- **0 and datediff(m, @d1, @d2)** this condition gives us all the `number`s we need to generate a `first-of-month` date for each month between @d1 and @d2, inclusive of both months
- **and dateadd(m,datediff(m,0,@d1)+v.number,0) between @d1 and @d2** the final filter to verify that the `first-of-month` date generated is between @d1 and @d2

---

Performance comparison against marc_s's code

Summary

```
8220 ms (CTE)
4173 ms (master..spt_values)
```

Test

```
declare @t table (dt datetime)
declare @d datetime
declare @i int
set nocount on

set @d = GETDATE()
set @i = 0
while @i < 10000
begin
insert @t select * from dbo.getfirstofmonth('20090102', '20100506')
delete @t
set @i = @i + 1
end

print datediff(ms, @d, getdate())

set @d = GETDATE()
set @i = 0
while @i < 10000
begin
insert @t select * from dbo.fnfirstofmonths('20090102', '20100506')
delete @t
set @i = @i + 1
end
print datediff(ms, @d, getdate())

Performante
```

Comment: @cyberkiwi: send me an e-mail to my account in my profile - I'll be happy to send you my query and screenshots of execution plans and estimated subtree costs and stuff like that....

Comment: @cyberkiwi: I'm seeing 28-43ms for my code vs. 68ms for your select - pretty consistently....

Comment: @cyberkiwi: ok, granted - the longer the period between the start and end date gets, the better your code holds up :-)

Comment: @marc You can add another answer. Using what code? the one above? Is there something wrong with the test as construct above?

Comment: @marc - just to be clear, CTE is the one that bombs at 100, unless OPTION MAXRECURSION is added. master..spt_values goes up to 2047 months or 170 years.

Answer (score 0):

It will loop just between the months involved (4 times in the example):

```
set dateformat mdy;
declare @date1 smalldatetime,@date2 smalldatetime,@i int
set @date1= '10-31-2010'
set @date2= '02-17-2011'
set @i=1

while(@i<=DATEDIFF(mm,@date1,@date2))
begin
    select  convert(smalldatetime,CONVERT(varchar(6),DATEADD(mm,@i,@date1),112)+'01',112)
    set     @i=@i+1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this isn't a function, but I'm going to throw this into the mix anyway.

```
select cal_date from calendar
where day_of_month = 1
and cal_date between '2011-01-01' and '2012-01-01'
```

This calendar table runs on a PostgreSQL server at work. I'll port it to SQL Server tonight, and run some speed comparisons. (Why? Because this stuff is fun, that's why.)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anybody is still reading this ...
I cannot imaging that any of the aforementioned functions is faster than this:

```
declare @DatFirst date = '20101031', @DatLast date = '21110217';

declare @DatFirstOfFirstMonth date = dateadd(day,1-day(@DatFirst),@DatFirst);

select  DatFirstOfMonth = dateadd(month,n,@DatFirstOfFirstMonth)
from    (
        select  top (datediff(month,@DatFirstOfFirstMonth,@DatLast)+1)
                n=row_number() over (order by (select 1))-1
        from    (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) a (n)
        cross join (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) b (n)
        cross join (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) c (n)
        cross join (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) d (n)
        ) x
```